# screen becomes weird when switching from ubuntu to windows on a dual boot system

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, windows-7-x64

I have a dual boot system with windows 7 and ubuntu. When I switch from winddows to ubuntu, the ubuntu OS starts up very smoothly. But when i switch to windows from ubuntu, the screen goes purple and i need to restart the system. Sometimes I need to restart it many times for windows to load properly. This also happens when I try to start windows first.

Please let me know the reason why this could be happening and solution if any.

Thanks in advance I

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by starting Windows through the boot CD and selecting the repair option. Windows got repaired and now is running fine.